# Angular / Loading component tag from language file

Tags: angular

I am adding an angular component with innerHTML

```
<span [innerHTML]="'prompt' | translate | safeHtml"></span>
```

This will load the content of the json key "prompt" of a language file. The safeHtml pipe will bypass security issues with the tags within the content.

The rendered source code looks fine which is the content in the json file:

```
<prompt [lang]="en"></prompt>
```

But the actual angular component hasn't connected with the tag. There is nothing happening within the class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because when Angular compiles, it adds some extra attributes to tags so that it can handle them on its own. Try inspecting a tag and you will see what I'm talking about. It does the same for CSS classes.

If you want to handle this element, you will have to find it with a good old `document.getElementByWhateverYouWant`

Comment: But is not possible to compile a component later. Can I trigger that?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, sorry but you will need to find something else